# Cycles modulo homological equivalence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives, hodge-theory, algebraic-cycles

Let $\text{CH}^p(X)_{\rm hom}$ be the abelian group of codimension $p$ algebraic cycles on a smooth projective variety over a field $k$, modulo homological equivalence. Is $\text{CH}^p(X)_{\rm hom}$ finitely generated?

If this is known, then what is a reference?

By homological equivalence I mean the subgroup of all cycles, generated by those that are killed by the cycle map to $\ell$-adic étale cohomology.

In characteristic zero, this map factors through the Betti cycle map, so homological equivalence is independent of $\ell$.

My question is about finite generatedness of $\text{CH}^p(X)_{\rm hom}$, and not $\text{CH}^p(X)_{\rm hom}\otimes\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}$. The latter is obvious since by definition it sits inside a finite dimensional $\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}$-vector space.

Comment: Slightly confused: you have by definition an injection ${\rm CH}^p(X)_{\rm hom}\hookrightarrow H^{2p}(X, \mathbf{Q}_\ell(p))$ (I assume $k$ algebraically closed), so by extension of scalars you get a map ${\rm CH}^p(X)_{\rm hom} \otimes \mathbf{Q}_\ell \to  H^{2p}(X, \mathbf{Q}_\ell(p))$, and you claim that this is "obviously" injective. Why? I believe that this is actually the key - if it were injective, we would know that ${\rm CH}^p(X)_{\rm hom}$ is f.g. modulo torsion (and you can use $\mathbf{Z}_\ell$ cohomology to handle the $\ell$-torsion too).

Comment: (And of course with Betti cohomology you see immediately that $CH^p(X)_{\rm hom}$ is f.g.)

Comment: Oh I see. We know the map $\text{CH}^p(X)_{\rm hom}\otimes\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}\to H^{2p}(X,\mathbf{Q}_{\ell})(p)$ is injective in char zero *because* it comes as the $\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}$ extension of scalars of the cycle map on Betti cohomology, and $\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}$ is flat.

Comment: So finite generatedness is unknown in char p. Am I wrong?

Comment: Unknown to me. Waiting for the experts to weigh in!